# Relationships and Channel Videos

Tags: relationships, channel-videos

This is the first time that I'm using the new Realationships field and I can't seem to get it to work with Channel Videos.

I am trying to display all videos from my relationship field "{related_entries}" from the channel "videos".

Here is my template code:

```
<div>
<ul>

{exp:channel:entries channel="video_courses" disable="categories|category-fields|member-data|pagination"}
{related_videos}
{exp:channel_videos:videos prefix="cv"}


<li><a href="{title_permalink='videos/view'}" class="image"><img src="{cv:img_url_hd}" alt="image01" /><h2><span>{title}</span></h2></a></li>

{/exp:channel_videos:videos}

{/related_videos}
{/exp:channel:entries}

  </ul>
</div>
```

However it is not outputting anything. Any thoughts appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The related_videos tag pair will loop through any you have selected, and for each loop you need to tell channel_videos which video you're looking for. So you could use the entry id parameter, something like:

```
{related_videos}
    {exp:channel_videos:videos prefix="cv" entry_id="{related_videos:entry_id}"}
        <li><a href="{title_permalink='videos/view'}" class="image"><img src="{cv:img_url_hd}" alt="image01" /><h2><span>{related_videos:title}</span></h2></a></li>
    {/exp:channel_videos:videos}
{/related_videos}
```

using the related_videos for a prefix to point to children variables in your video channel. You also might have to change the formatting for the permalink.